# Category location styling

Tags: categories, css

http://www.milknhny.co.uk/DVine/?page_id=19

Please can someone help, i have added the categories, however it appears to be off line. I have tried to style this in a class but this screws up the whole thing.

I wrapped like the below but it seemed to apply to the whole of the div it was wrapped in

```
<div class="classname"><?php get_category(); ?></div>
```

Please can someone assist, do i edit the main style within the themes?

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to show? review `get_category()` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category

Comment: Hi Michael, I have now corrected this. Thankyou for your assistance. Kirsty

Comment: does this mean the problem is solved? if yes, you can add the solution as an answer; if not, you could edit your question and add the current code, and describe the problem in more detail.

Comment: Hi Michael, apologies thought i had :) Editted :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way i fixed the issue was to insert the following code into my main CSS.

```
.post-categories, .post-categories li {display:inline; padding: 0px;}
```

I hope this helps others in this issue in the future.